# Need css help to force elements on single line

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML...

```
<div class="tester">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst </div>
    <div>c</div>
</div>
```

How would I change this css to make the 3 divs above appear in a single row?  The middle div I wish to clip if it overflows its boundary.

```
.tester { width: 300px; overflow: auto; background-color: #c5c5c5; }
    .tester > div { float: left; overflow: hidden; }
        .tester > div:last-child { float: right; width: 50px; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/B9ttJ/)

*** UPDATE ***

**Clarification**
I want to keep the width at 300px, and the middle element should clip if it exceeds it's bounding box.  The bounding box of the first element is determined by it's size.  The bounding box of the last element is set at 50px.  So the middle element should clip.

Comment: the middle div must have a specified size to have a boundary to overflow (which should be hidden).

Comment: Not possible with css only - not unless you use percentages to set the widths but as you want to have the content of the first div define the width of the second then you'll need to use javascript... is that a problem?

Comment: After your clarification: I think if the second div has no specified width it always will float to the space it needs within the upper parents bounding box (= next line) and won't clip.

Comment: Using a <table> might be an option

Comment: @JoeSpurling A table perhaps would be the best option because the only reason to use tables is to build tables. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use display inline, here's a little demo:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B9ttJ/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="tester">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst
    <div>c</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tester div {
    display:inline;
}
```

And the result:

> a abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl
>   mnop qrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst c

Comment: I don't see how this deals with the issue of preventing overflow in the middle div.

Answer (score 2):

use the display property

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: didn't seem to help.  do you have an example?